# Move JsonBody to a different class file

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to move a jsonBody Object to a different class file, but when Im calling the method from another class the json attributes doesn't get passed correctly 
Any ideas on how to solve?

This is what I'm trying with.

```
public void WhenIPerformPostOperatiom(string url, Table table) {
 string productId = "11234";
 _settings.Request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);

     JsonObjects jsonBody = new JsonObjects();
     jsonBody.AQuestions(productId, table);

 _settings.Request.AddJsonBody(jsonBody);
}
```

and the object.

```
public class JsonObjects
    {
       public void AQuestions(string productId,Table table)
        {
            dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
            var jsonBody = new AccountRoot()
            {
                productId = productId,
                questions = new[]
                  {
                       new Questions() {
                        questionId = "b2b-2.01",
                        question ="Q1",
                        answers = new []
                        {
                            new Answers(){
                            answerValue = data.answerValue1
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to get copied?  `AQuestions` only sets local variables which are not accessible outside of the method.

Comment: Yeah thats the issue, that the variables only sets locally and I want the JsonBody to be created in a different file so I can use post operation. 
This works if I have the JsonBody in the method WhenIPerformPostOperatiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `data` and `jsonBody` member variables if you want them accessible after calling `AQuestions(...)`.  The type of jsonBody could be object if you want it to hold any type... but that makes it hard to use for anything other than storing data to be walked by reflection...

```
public class JsonObjects
{
    public dynamic data;
    public AccountRoot jsonBody;

    public void AQuestions(string productId,Table table)
    {
        data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
        jsonBody = new AccountRoot()
        {
            productId = productId,
            questions = new[]
            {
                new Questions() 
                {
                    questionId = "b2b-2.01",
                    question ="Q1",
                    answers = new []
                    {
                        new Answers()
                        {
                            answerValue = data.answerValue1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```